# Find all possible words that start with a particular character and display in C (Dictionary implementation using Binary trees)

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a function which takes a node structure and a alphabet as arguments and based on that alphabet it should show me all the possible words starting with that alphabet in the binary tree.But the function I have written just shows me the 1st word starting with that alphabet.
Any help would be appreciated...thanks
Here is the node structure,function defination and the call that I have written:

//Node structure

```
    typedef struct treeNode
     {
       char word[100];
       char mean[1024];
       struct treeNode *right;
       struct treeNode *left;
      }treeNode;

   //Function definition

   treeNode *first(treeNode *node,char alpha)
   {
    if(node==NULL)
    return;
    else if(alpha==node->word[0])
    {
    first(node->right,alpha);
      printf("Entry for %c found:\n",alpha);
      printf("%s means: %s .\n",node->word,node->mean);
     first(node->left,alpha);
    }
    else
     return;
      }
   //Fuction call

   case 5:printf("Enter the 1st letter to find the corresponding    words\n");
scanf(" %c",&alpha);
first(root,alpha);
break;
```

Comment: Is this a binary search tree with strings as keys? If so please consider a more appropriate data structure such as a trie.

Comment: we have not started working with tries as of now so not clear  with that concept....thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

After finding the node which starts with the given letter you should loop through the child until it has no child or to the leaf to check if that node has still children which may have a word which starts with the given character.
Btw why is the function name has a return type of **treeNode**? are you trying to return the node which has the same first letter of the given character? or you are just going to display it?

What I'm posting is just displaying it so I changed the function return type

```
void first(treeNode *node,char alpha)
{
if(node==NULL)
     //do something
else if(node->word[0] < alpha)
     first(node->right,alpha);
else if(node->word[0] > alpha)
     first(node->left,alpha);
else
{
     first(node->left,alpha);
     printf("Entry for %c found:\n",alpha);
     printf("%s means: %s .\n",node->word,node->mean);
     first(node->right,alpha);
}
}
```

[image]

[image: Insert function]

[image]

[image: Main]

Comment: hey thanks it works...but now there is a small issue....if i enter a letter for which there are no entries in the tree it skips 1 itteration and goes to the next ittraton...how do i catch is exception??

Comment: I don't understand the question. But if you want to a find an element in a Tree you really should traverse until the leaf even though you logically know that the element is not in the Tree. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: I have posted the Updated function defination. there are still a few bugs...plz help me fix them

Comment: My first comment is that you still need to **look for the element in the tree**. Your current code doesn't work on all cases. 
What if the element is not in the root but it is in one its child.

Comment: thanks for the edit...n btw no im not returning the node....it ws jus that i have copied the structure from the abve function n forgot to change it...thanks for bringing it to my notice....btw the code tht u have sent i had tried somthing similar earlier bt there is a problem with tht approach i.e
say the word are stored this way
b measn ball
a means ant
aa means apple
Stored in this exact order then if i try to search for all words beging with 'a' it dsnt show me anything
also
b measn ball
a means ant
aa means apple
if words are stored in dis order den n i search for 'b' o/p is
b means ball

Comment: Is this a binary search tree? or ordinary binary tree? Because I think my code should work if it  is a **BST**

Comment: binary search tree

Comment: no dude not wrking jus displays the 1st eement in the alphabetically order in the tree :( :(

Comment: I tried it now and my code really works. Try displaying your BST maybe "ant" and "apple" node were not really inserted

Comment: i tried dude n yes they are inserted :( how do i send u a screenshoot of my o/p. o cn i send u my code if u want....u cn run it and see

Comment: Dude try entring 'b' 1st wen u creating the tree and den enter 'a'  and everything subsequently n try.....wont work i think

Comment: I inserted b first you can check it in the preorder traversal **b** is the root which means it is inserted first

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an *in-order* traversal of the tree, with some constraints on starting and stopping.

Find out more [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order).

In short:

1. Maintain a state flag, "showing," that indicates whether you should show the word or not. At start, `showing = FALSE`.
2. Perform your search for the first word starting with whatever character.
3. Set `showing = TRUE` and do what you must to emit the word.
4. Convert from a search to a traverse.
5. Continue until you run out of words starting with that character.
6. Set `showing = FALSE` and return upwards.